# Python tkinter label formulas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

how can I make a label with a formula and whenever I change the value in entry, does it automatically change the value in the label? As if it were excel cells with formulas. And in case it would have to be invisible (without content) while the entry is empty.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
ent1 = tk.Entry(root)
lab1 = tk.Label(root,text='Price')
ent2 = tk.Entry(root)
lab2 = tk.Label(root,text='Quantity')
lab3 = tk.Label(root,text='') #lab3 formula = float(ent1.get()) * int(ent2.get())

lab1.pack() 
ent1.pack()
lab2.pack()
ent2.pack()
lab3.pack()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already, or looked online?

Comment: Of course, I would not waste time asking. The problem is that I do not even know how to search for the name of it. Examples that came close to that use buttons with functions and I would like to do without buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `trace` method to execute a function when a variable changes.

```
import tkinter as tk

def update(*args):
    try:
        output_var.set(price_var.get() * quantity_var.get())
    except (ValueError, tk.TclError):
        output_var.set('invalid input')

root = tk.Tk()

lab1 = tk.Label(root,text='Price')
price_var = tk.DoubleVar()
price_var.trace('w', update) # call the update() function when the value changes
ent1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=price_var)

lab2 = tk.Label(root,text='Quantity')
quantity_var = tk.DoubleVar()
quantity_var.trace('w', update)
ent2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=quantity_var)

output_var = tk.StringVar()
lab3 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=output_var) #lab3 formula = float(ent1.get()) * int(ent2.get())

lab1.pack()
ent1.pack()
lab2.pack()
ent2.pack()
lab3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked the way I wanted it to, but as I type the numbers, showing up some errors, is it normal?

Comment: @ThomasCaio No, it shouldn't. What errors is it showing?

Comment: when I delete the 0.0 and 0 of the entrys to put other values ////

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 505, in get
    return self._tk.getint(value)
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got ""

Comment: @ThomasCaio With my code? That's very odd. I tested it and it works well for me, Windows and Linux, python 3.4 and 3.6.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/ThomasCaio/Desktop/desc.py", line 5, in update
    output_var.set(price_var.get() * quantity_var.get())
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 526, in get
    return self._tk.getdouble(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

Comment: happens when I delete the 0.0 of the first entry. Win10, py3.6.3

Comment: in linux lite, another error occurs soon after, but the program continues to run normally. LinuxLite3.6 py3.5.2:

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxlite1/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1134, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1557, in __call__
    self.widget._report_exception()
AttributeError: 'DoubleVar' object has no attribute '_report_exception'

Comment: Still no idea. I can fix it by just catching that error as well (I edited my response) but I'd love to know why you are throwing that error when I am not.

Comment: This is really weird. Thanks for the answer!